# How to create cylinder which is thick from the bottom and thin from the top

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am using the following nodes to make a cylinder with loop cuts.

I wanted to know how I could make the mesh thin from the top and thick from the centre.

[image]

Comment: can u make a sketch or 3D model manually of what exactly u want to accomplish? u mean like a pipe that has thick and gradually tapered thin walling?

Comment: Yes, Like a pipe that is gradually thin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a *Cone* mesh primitive with both *Radius Top* and *Radius Bottom* being non-zero:

[image]

Comment: But I also want to have procedural loop cuts.

Comment: I think cone primitive can do loop cuts. So thanks.